# Automation on PowerBI using Python

Tags: python-3.x, powerbi, pywinauto, pyautogui, powerbi-desktop

I want to write python script to automate some process in dashboard of PowerBI.
My use cases are about:

1. Open powerBI and click to page 1 of dashboard.
2. click some filter and then capture the screen.
3. click the other pages and do step 2.

I try to run some command in https://github.com/dubravcik/pbixrefresher-python. It can open powerBI and refresh the data. So, I adapt some script from it.

Now, I can use *pywinauto* and *pyautogui* to do the above process. It can refer to buttons in ribbon tab but ***I want to refer to page tab and filter in the dashboard***. *pyautogui* can refer to position in the screen by the pixel but it doesn't work in different resolution screen. Moreover, it hasn't exact format in each page of the dashboard.

I try to use *swapy64bit* to find a object value but it doesn't work in complex program like powerBI.

So, my problem is how to reference object in dashboard from powerBI (page, filter) using its unique value (such as variable name) instead of screen position.

Regards,

[Example of my powerBI dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsHh6.png)

Comment: SWAPY is outdated and supports old pywinauto 0.5.4 only. For latest pywinauto 0.6.4 we have 2 backends: new one is UIA (UI Automation API). I’d strongly recommend reading the Getting Started Guide first.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Thanks for your reply. I read http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#. But in the case that page name or filter isn't static, how I can handle this? For example how can I automate to click page1, page2 and page 3 of the dashboard (in the below tab)

Comment: Well, if you need an access by Automation ID (it's usually variable name), you have to use `backend="uia"` when creating `Application` object. If `auto_id` criterion in `child_window` doesn't help, selecting tab by index is the only way probably.

Comment: OK, i will try to use Inspect.exe to access object auto_id. If it doesn't work, I would have to select by index in pixel. (Please clarify me if I'm misunderstanding, thanks a lot again)

Comment: "By index" means "by number of tab". I'm not much familiar with PyAutoGUI interface and can talk about pywinauto only.

Comment: Oh, i just get you point. Now, i can access automation_id (application's variable) and I can click some button in ribbon tab. But i'm still question on how to selecting tab by index. How could I get number of tab or filter in dashboard automatically?.

Comment: `.TabControl.get_selected_tab()` and `.TabControl.select(index)`

Comment: You can call `.wrapper_object()` for window specification and explore list of wrapper methods using standard Python function `dir(wrapper)`. When you calling `.click()` or whatever Python can hide `.wrapper_object()` call. But when you're debugging the script, explicit `.wrapper_object()` call is pretty useful.